# How to set UI interface orientation programmatically in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, orientation, screen-orientation, swift5

For my game logic, I have to lock the screen orientation and set the orientation programmatically triggered by Button in SwiftUI. How should I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.rotate()
        }) {
            Text("Rotate")
        }
    }

    func rotate() -> Void {
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will work for changing orientation. But how to lock the orientation of the gravity effect?

Comment: This solution used to be popular, but setting orientation through setValue on UIDevice crashes now in iOS16 and caused me a lot of trouble. See discussion at developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712247 .

Comment: showing this waring in console `BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Setting UIDevice.orientation is not supported. Please use UIWindowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(_:)`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is here, but I wonder there is some better method.

```
import SwiftUI
class HostVC<T>: UIHostingController<T> where T: View {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {ContentView.autoRotate}
}
struct ContentView: View {
    static var autoRotate: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Rotate") {
            let r: Int
            switch UIDevice.current.value(forKey: HomeView.keyOrientation) {
            case let i as Int where i == UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue: r = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
            default: r = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
            }
            ContentView.autoRotate = true
            UIDevice.current.setValue(r, forKey: HomeView.keyOrientation)
            ContentView.autoRotate = false
        }
    }
}
```